# Error with calling a method from another method in the same class

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods

I can't seem to figure out what is going on with this GPA calculator program I'm trying to build. The problem is in the `printTranscript` method of `Student` class. The method calls `getGPA` method of the same class, which returns a double, the output is some massive number instead of a standard GPA.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Student stud("Lebron", 23232);
    stud.addCourse("Passing", 3, 'A');
    stud.addCourse("Finals Record", 4, 'D');
    stud.printTranscript();
    return 0;
}
```

Student.h:

```
#include "Course.h"
#include <vector>
class Student{
private:
    string name;
    int studentID;
    vector<Course> courses;
public:
    Student(){
        name = "No Name";
        studentID = 0;
    }
    Student(string n, int ID){
        name = n;
        studentID = ID;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
    void setName(string n){
        name = n;
    }
    int getID(){
        return studentID;
    }
    void setID(int ID){
        studentID = ID;
    }
    void addCourse(string, int, char);
    void addCourse(Course);
    double getGPA();
    void printTranscript();
};
```

Student.cpp:

```
#include "Student.h"
void Student::addCourse(string name, int credits, char grade){
    courses.push_back(Course(name,credits,grade));
}
void Student::addCourse(Course c){
    courses.push_back(c);
}
double Student::getGPA(){
    double gradePoints, totalCredits;
    for(int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++){
        if(courses[i].getGrade() == 'A'){
            gradePoints += (4.0 * courses[i].getCredits());
            totalCredits += courses[i].getCredits();
        }
        else if(courses[i].getGrade() == 'B'){
            gradePoints += (3.0 * courses[i].getCredits());
            totalCredits += courses[i].getCredits();
        }
        else if(courses[i].getGrade() == 'C'){
            gradePoints += (2.0 * courses[i].getCredits());
            totalCredits += courses[i].getCredits();
        }
        else if (courses[i].getGrade() == 'D'){
            gradePoints += (1.0 * courses[i].getCredits());
            totalCredits += courses[i].getCredits();
        }
    }
    return (gradePoints / totalCredits);
}
void Student::printTranscript(){
    cout << "Transcript for: " << name << endl;
    cout << "============================" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++){
        cout << "Course: " << courses[i].getID() << endl;
        cout << "Grade: " << courses[i].getGrade() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Overall GPA: " << getGPA() << endl;
}
```

Course.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Course{
private:
    string courseID; // Course name
    int numCredits; // Instructor
    char letterGrade; // Textbook
public:
    Course(string ID, int credits, char grade){ // Assign the course name.
        courseID = ID;
        numCredits = credits;
        letterGrade = grade;
    }
    string getID(){
        return courseID;
    }
    void setID(string ID){
        courseID = ID;
    }
    int getCredits(){
        return numCredits;
    }
    void setCredits(int credits){
        numCredits = credits;
    }
    char getGrade(){
        return letterGrade;
    }
    void setGrade(char grade){
        letterGrade =  grade;
    }
};
```

Sorry for the long bit of code, but I can't seem to figure out why output in main is giving me:

```
Transcript for: Lebron James
============================
Course: Passing
Grade: A

Course: Finals Record
Grade: D

Overall GPA: 2.2321e+230
```

If I cout stud.getGPA in the main class as a separate statement, it works fine. What explains the massively large number being output here when called from another method of the same class, and how is this fixed?

Sorry for the long code, but I didn't want to miss anything, as I am still at the beginning stages of C++.

Comment: you don't initialise your gradePoints or totalCredits variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [dcl.init/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#7):

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
>     ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen
>     through overload resolution. The constructor thus selected is called,
>     with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.
> - If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> - **Otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

You are directly doing some operation `+=`:

```
totalCredits += courses[i].getCredits();
```

but forget to initialize the variable. Don't assume everything will be set to `zero` initially.

Thus, Initialize `totalCredits` to `0.0`.

**Adding `-Wuninitialized`**:

As suggested by @1201ProgramAlarm, use `-Wuninitialized` to flag uninitialized variables.

```
warning: 'totalCredits' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

If you want to treat warnings as errors, just add the flag `-Werror`

Comment: Interesting. Shouldn't this be an error then? What causes the large number?

Comment: @KevinMoy It isn't an error, but if you crank the warning level for your compiler up you should get a warning about using an uninitialized variable.